# Can many JobPosting items be placed in the same file?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

Is this good way to code JSON-LD for Schema.org’s `JobPosting`?

I place a number of `JobPosting` items in the same file. Is this working properly? Is this correct way?

```html
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
            "@context" : "http://schema.org/",
            "@type" : "JobPosting",
            "title" : "Job1",
            "description" : "",
            "datePosted" : "2018-10-26",
            "validThrough" : "2018-11-02",
            "hiringOrganization": {
                 ...
            },
        "jobLocation": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": {
                    ...
          }
        },                    
    }
</script>


<script type="application/ld+json"> {
                        "@context" : "http://schema.org/",
                        "@type" : "JobPosting",
                        "title" : "Job2",
                        "description" : "",
                        "datePosted" : "2018-10-26",
                        "validThrough" : "2018-11-02",
                        "hiringOrganization": {
                             ...
                        },
                    "jobLocation": {
                    "@type": "Place",
                    "address": {
                                ...
                      }
                    },                    
                }
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
                    "@context" : "http://schema.org/",
                    "@type" : "JobPosting",
                    "title" : "Job3",
                    "description" : "",
                    "datePosted" : "2018-10-26",
                    "validThrough" : "2018-11-02",
                    "hiringOrganization": {
                         ...
                    },
                "jobLocation": {
                "@type": "Place",
                "address": {
                            ...
                  }
                },                    
            }
</script>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
                    "@context" : "http://schema.org/",
                    "@type" : "JobPosting",
                    "title" : "job - n",
                    "description" : "",
                    "datePosted" : "2018-10-26",
                    "validThrough" : "2018-11-02",
                    "hiringOrganization": {
                         ...
                    },
                "jobLocation": {
                "@type": "Place",
                "address": {
                            ...
                  }
                },                    
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to get a specific rich result, or do you ask generally?

Comment: @unor I want to get all job posting . I write all script in same page .so I ask. Is this a correct way . Whether it generate all job posting or generate a first one ?

Comment: I was asking about rich results (as you added the SEO tag, and rich results are typically the only SEO aspect of structured data): Do you want to get a rich result for the page where you have these multiple `JobPosting` items? If yes, which rich result / which search engine? [The one from Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting?hl=en)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct to do that, but you can also just use an array:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
[{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "JobPosting",
    "title": "Job1",
    "description": "",
    "datePosted": "2018-10-26",
    "validThrough": "2018-11-02",
    "hiringOrganization": {
        ...
    }
    ,
    "jobLocation": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": {
            ...
        }
    }
},
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "JobPosting",
    "title": "Job2",
    "description": "",
    "datePosted": "2018-10-26",
    "validThrough": "2018-11-02",
    "hiringOrganization": {
        ...
    }
    ,
    "jobLocation": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": {
            ...
        }
    }
}]
</script>
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723531/best-json-ld-practices-using-multiple-script-elements